# Why can't I add an edit summary within the 5 minutes grace period

Tags: support, bug

I edited the body and tags of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/760140/how-to-know-if-an-application-is-using-system-proxy-and-tor-network). After I saved my changes, I realized that I forgot to add an Edit Summary. Since I was within the 5 minutes grace period, I just went back to the question, clicked on edit, added my summary and saved it.

[image]

But my summary wasn't saved for some reason.  I repeated the steps just to be sure - with no success.

[image]

Can anyone reproduce this or am I the only one seeing this?

Why are later added Edit Summaries not saved?

Comment: You didn't actually edit anything in your second edit.

Comment: it's a long standing bug - every time I try to repro it to report to meta, the summary gets saved :\

Answer (score 3):

I’ve seen this repeatedly. 
As Sathya♦ says, this is a bug – if you do an edit, but don’t change the body (or the tags?),
the system thinks you didn’t change anything. 
My workaround: when I want to edit my Edit Summary, I add a space to the end of a line in the body. 
Then, if I still have time, I edit again and delete it.